# Iterating over a string by only changing one element in the string

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on a script with Selenium that needs to find and click through a long list of items.  The items all have the IDs `id="listContainer_row:##"` where the ## ranges from 0 to 645.  I am trying to write a for loop that can iterate just the number at the end of the ID string so I can interact with each link in turn.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?:

```
for i in range(645):
    id = 'listContainer_row:' + str(i)
```

Comment: Yes, thank you!  My brain has just shut down this afternoon.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, you can just *partially match the `id` attribute value*:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id^=listContainer_row]")  # starts with
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("[id*=listContainer_row]")  # contains
```

As an implicit benefit, there is no hardcoded magic `645` number here involved.